# SQL split the first name with underscore

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to split the first name from the middle name or middle initial when there's an underscore in the name.  I was able to split the first name from the middle name when there is a space, but having trouble with the underscore.

I would like to keep it all together in the case statement if possible.

```
    SELECT 
[first name]
,  SUBSTRING([first name], 1,
                  CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(REVERSE([first name]), 2, 1) = ' '
                       THEN CHARINDEX(' ', [first name]) - 1
                       ELSE LEN([first name])
                  END) AS FirstName ,
        CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(REVERSE([first name]), 2, 1) = ' '
             THEN SUBSTRING([first name], LEN([first name]), 1)
             ELSE NULL
        END AS MiddleName
,   [Last Name]

FROM nametable
```

[image]

Comment: Why don't you replace the underscore with a space ?

Comment: no, I want to remove the underscore and separate the middle name or initial into the middle name column.

Comment: Can you show me an example of what you mean?

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Comment: What if the name is two first names. "Sally Rae". Maybe that's what the underscore is meant to convey. That the 2nd part is not a middle name, but instead the 2nd part of the first name. What about "Jo Ann"... her first name is "Jo Ann"... not "Jo".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following example uses two `case` *expressions* to separate one column into two. It makes use of a feature of `Substring`: no error is raised if the specified length exceeds the length of the input string.

Note that the sample data is not an image of data, but useful data.

```
declare @Samples as Table ( Name VarChar(20) );

insert into @Samples ( Name ) values
  ( 'Billy' ), ( 'Billy Bob' ), ( 'Billy_Joe' ), ( 'Edgar_7' ),
  ( '_' ), ( 'X_' ), ( '_Y' ), ( '' );

select Name,
  case
    when CharIndex( '_', Name ) > 0 then Left( Name, CharIndex( '_', Name ) - 1 )
    else Name end as FirstName,
  case
    when CharIndex( '_', Name ) > 0 then Substring( Name, CharIndex( '_', Name ) + 1, 20 )
    else NULL end as MiddleName
  from @Samples;
```

Answer (score 3):

Add the REPLACE function inline:

```
 SELECT 
    [first name]
    ,  SUBSTRING([first name], 1,
                      CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(REVERSE(REPLACE([first name], '_', ' ')), 2, 1) = ' '
                           THEN CHARINDEX(' ', REPLACE([first name], '_', ' ')) - 1
                           ELSE LEN([first name])
                      END) AS FirstName ,
            CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(REVERSE(REPLACE([first name], '_', ' ')), 2, 1) = ' '
                 THEN SUBSTRING(REPLACE([first name], '_', ' '), LEN([first name]), 1)
                 ELSE NULL
            END AS MiddleName
    ,   [Last Name]

    FROM nametable
```

Comment: I'm still getting the underscore in the first name.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to sample data provided by [@HABO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56640735/1666800), you can try this too:

```
SELECT L.Name,
       L.FirstName,
       CASE L.MiddleName WHEN '' THEN NULL ELSE L.MiddleName END AS MiddleName
FROM
(
    SELECT P.Name,
           REPLACE(SUBSTRING(P.UnderscoredName, 1, P.UnderscoreIndex), '_', '') AS FirstName,
           REPLACE(SUBSTRING(P.UnderscoredName, P.UnderscoreIndex, LEN(P.UnderscoredName) - P.UnderscoreIndex + 1),'_','') AS MiddleName
    FROM
    (
        SELECT K.Name,
               K.UnderscoredName,
               CHARINDEX('_', K.UnderscoredName) AS UnderscoreIndex
        FROM
        (
            SELECT Name,
                   REPLACE(CASE WHEN Name LIKE N'%[_]%' THEN Name ELSE Name + '_' END,' ','_') AS UnderscoredName
            FROM @Samples
        ) AS K
    ) AS P
) AS L;
```

Comment: Your solution does not output `NULL` for the middle name when none is present. The OP's picture of data shows nulls. (My answer does not produce nulls in some cases, e.g. `'X_'`, but I included various edge cases in my sample data to demonstrate what happens in cases not specified by the OP.) As a rule integer operations are more efficient than string operations. Adding an underscore to a string and then using `Replace` to remove it when you could simply subtract `1` from the length is overkill.

Comment: And `Replace` is a bigger hammer than is needed. Try adding `'0_1_2'` as input and comparing results. Granted, the OP never stated either 0 or 1 underscores would be present, but ... . From [`String_Split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017): "The output rows might be in any order. The order is not guaranteed to match the order of the substrings in the input string."

Comment: @HABO thanks for your great comments. I have updated my answer and now it returns NULL for MiddleName. About multiple underscore problem that you mentioned, in this case the problem area does not declared this problem, so we need to know what should happen in that case. as we do not have clear picture about it, so I think we could simply ignore it. About the ordering problem of the String_Split function, you are right, how ever I had "partIndex" which helps me to order the output in right way, however I removed that query, because I found it useless.

Comment: @HABO The knowledge sharing atmosphere of the stackoverflow is amazing and I really love it to talk with professionals like you around a problem. Thank you and Thanks Stackoverflow